# Knights and Knaves

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

You are visiting an island with two types of people: knights who always tell the
truth and knaves who always lie. From among the thousands of people who live
on the island, you meet six people who each have something to tell you. Use their
comments to determine who among them are knight(s) and knave(s).

Person A: The six of us are knaves!

Person B: At least three of us are knights.

Person C: At most three of us are knights.

Person D: Exactly five of us are knights.

Person E: Exactly two of us are knights.

Person F: Exactly one of us is a knight.

Comment: Hi Emily, and welcome to Puzzling :) Please can you tell us where you found this puzzle, as we need to make sure the source is declared in the question if being reproduced from elsewhere (for reasons of copyright, plagiarism, etc.). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

> C and E are knights, A, B, D and F are all knaves.

---

Going through:

> A must be a knave, as if they're telling the truth, then they're no longer a knave - so they must be lying. This makes at least one knave.
>
> F must also be a knave, as if they're telling the truth, no-one else can. But that would mean C is also telling the truth - contradiction - so F is lying. That makes A and F knaves.
>
> D now cannot be true, as there is at most 4 knights. So D is also a knave. A, D and F are all knaves. Only B, C and E are now left.
>
> E now must be telling the truth. If E is lying, then C is true and B is false, making 5 knaves and 1 knight - but this would make F's statement true again. So E is telling the truth.
>
> B must now be lying as we know there are exactly 2 knights. So C and E are knights, and the rest are knaves.

Answer (score 0):

The same conclusion as the other answerers came to, but trying to be more explicit about all of the steps to get there:

Regarding Person A's statement:

> A knight can never say that, so person A must be a knave.

Regarding person C's statement:

> The statements by persons A, D, E, and F are mutually contradictory, so at most one of them is a knight. Even if persons B and C were both knights, that would still only be three total, so this must be true, and so person C is a knight.

Regarding person D's statement:

> We already established that person C is a knight, and person D's statement contradicts person C's statement, so person D must be a knave.

Regarding person F's statement:

> A knight can only say that if everyone else is a knave, but we already established that person C is a knight, so person F must be a knave, and so this must be false.

Regarding person B's statement:

> We already established that persons A, D, and F are knaves. For this to be true, persons B, C, and E would then all have to be knights, but this is impossible since persons B and E's statements are contradictory. Therefore, this must be false, and so person B is a knave.

Regarding person E's statement:

> We already established that person C is a knight, and that persons A, B, D, and F are knaves. At first, it seems like everyone's answers would be consistent whether person E were a knight or a knave. But remember that person F's statement must be false, and that we've only found one knight so far. This means that person E must be a second knight.

Summary of conclusions:

> Persons C and E are knights. Persons A, B, D, and F are knaves.